# Unable to Download libspotify for mac application

Tags: macos, spotify

When trying to run the sample mac app included in the github repo for libspotify, I get the following error:

```
Could Not untar libspotify-12.1.45-Darwin-universal.zip
```

I have tried to download the zip myself by going to the Spotify developer page. However, this version is not shown. 
What version should I download for building the sample mac app?

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that - it's fixed now. Please delete any zip files from the "Mac Framework" folder in CocoaLibSpotify and try again.